# vs2017 missing web.config in .Net Core Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-config, asp.net-core-mvc

I just noticed that whenever we create a new project, web.config file is not added to the project anymore.

According to [this link](https://zimmergren.net/using-appsettings-json-instead-of-web-config-in-net-core-projects/) , we can use `appsettings.json` as the replacement of `web.config`.  And I am already using it to store some settings and using in my app.

However, I don't know how to generate `forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"` in the `web.config` file while doing the publishing.  We are using WindowsAuthentication for the website and it's not appended on the generated `web.config` file.

I tried to add that setting in the appsettings.json like the following and it's not still appending.  I need to manually edit the web.config file on the webserver.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "forwardWindowsAuthToken" :  true
}
```

It works when I added web.config file in my project and add `forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"` in the code.

Since `appsettings.json` is replacing `web.config` file, I am not sure whether my approach is correct or not.  Am I doing right or is there a way to add that code in the generated `web.config` file automatically?

Comment: That's not entirely correct. appsetting.json is replacing configuration that was in web.config before, but it do not replace the web.config itself. web.config is still used for IIS related settings, like logging and setting the handler and other IIS stuff. But it's not used when you exclusively host on linux or mac or run it with kestrel (console/self-host) within a docker container etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have `web.config` with required configuration in VS2017 .NET Core project, and during publish `dotnet` would replace `processPath`and `arguments` attributes automatically. This did the trick in our deployment process.

Comment: `web.config` was created by VS2015 automatically and stayed after the upgrade, so I guess it's still can be considered as created manually.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand why MS get rid of the web.config file if it's still generated automatically and required for some settings.

Comment: Creating a standard .NET v4.6.2 MVC project would include `web.config` by default in VS2017. However .NET Core project can run as a stand-alone application using kestrel, and `web.config` is needed by IIS only. Maybe that was the logic behind Microsoft's decision...